# angularjs ng-repeat array index

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to print (based on array index) all array value?

At the moment, it print all the values.

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <td>Name</td>
           <td>Designation</td>
           <td>Total Credit Amount</td>
           <td>Total Debit Amount</td>
           <td>Related Companies</td>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="data in relTransactions track by $index">
          <td>{{data.name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.designation}}</td>
          <td>{{data.total_credit_amount}}</td>
          <td>{{data.total_debit_amount}}</td>
          <td>
              <button ng-click="openViewMore()">View More</button>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I try to get array value based on id but i got all array value in that table how i fix that

Comment: What do you intend to do based on array index?

Comment: Add your js code.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: @Develop Still unclear what you are asking.

Comment: let say suppose i have 4 view more button each have different response in array if i click 1st view more then i need to print 1st array respone only. now it print all array valu

Comment: Provide the code of `openViewMore()` function.

Comment: $scope.openViewMore = function() {
      modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        size: 'lg',
        templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/insights/insightsDashboard/viewmore.tpl.html',
        scope: $scope,
        controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
          $scope.closeModal = function(){
             $modalInstance.close();
          }
        }
      });
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want access the array object inside the `openViewMore` then pass the index as parameter and access array like this.

```
<button ng-click="openViewMore($index)">View More</button> 
$scope.openViewMore = function(index) {
    console.log($scope.relTransactions[index])
}
```

OR you can pass the object as parameter to the function.

```
<button ng-click="openViewMore(data)">View More</button> 
$scope.openViewMore = function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: it print all value in that

Comment: <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
      <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in relTransactions by index">
       <tr ng-repeat="cList in value.relatedCompaniesList">
        <td>{{cList.company_name}}</td>
        <td>{{cList.total_debit_amount}}</td>
        <td>{{cList.total_credit_amount}}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>

Comment: Sorry this is my table

Comment: @Develop so when do you call `openViewMore` method inside table

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your comments, You want to show data of array only when Somebody clicks 'view more' of that array Item.

You can use ng-show based on $index. On clicking view more , change expanded index via functional call. I have written a small example have a look below.

[**Try on CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpMNgb)

```
  <html>

  <body ng-app>
        <h1>Click on view More below </h1>
    <div id="main" ng-app ng-controller="appController">
        <div ng-repeat="data in arr track by $index">
            <input type='button' value="View more" ng-click="showMore($index)"/> 
            <spna>item {{ $index }}</span>
            <span ng-show='expanded == $index'>{{data.name}}</span>
            <br><br>
            </div>
</div>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

In your controller:

```
function appController($scope){
    $scope.arr = [ {name:'one'},{name:'two'},{name:'three'}];

    $scope.showMore = function(i)
    {
        $scope.expanded = i;
    }
}
```